# Unity: "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set." message

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

My old project gave me this error after I change my system to apple m1 .

"USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set."

when I use "SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync" func, immediately I get "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set." message. why it can be?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class authManager : Singleton<authManager>
{

    public FirebaseAuth auth;
    public DBmanager dbManager;
    public bool errorCheckSignIn, errorCheckSignUp;

    loginMain loginMainSc;

    private void Start()
    {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

        dbManager = DBmanager.Instance;
        errorCheckSignIn = false;
        errorCheckSignUp = false;
    }

    public void signIn(string email, string password)
    {
        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("canceled!");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("faulted!");
                errorCheckSignIn = true;
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                FirebaseUser currentUser = task.Result.User;
                dbManager.userData.userId = currentUser.UserId;
                dbManager.userData.email = email;

                Debug.Log("Giriş yapıldı.");
                //PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
                SceneManager.LoadScene("servers");
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried to set environment variables, sent and unset Firebase Auth emulator for Mac. tried to put inside of my code;

```
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST", "127.0.0.1:9099");
```

but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same error. Did you solve it?

Comment: I have same error any solution

Answer (score 0):

Same question appears in my project, I use Windows and when I ran my project in Unity editor, this error occurred. But when I release it to an Android APK, everything is fine. So, I visit the document of firebase, and find that you can't run your project in editor with normal firebase SDK, you need a desktop workflow SDK. But I have not tried it yet, because our team don't use firebase any more. Hope this can help you.

[image: firebase document with desktop workflow]

Answer (score 0):

That log message is no cause for alarm and can be disregarded unless you want to connect to the Firebase Auth Emulator.

The Firebase Unity SDK is built on top of the Firebase C++ SDK, which [logs "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set" at the Info level](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/b5b7e05b6a6e3c7ca4baadb7f15ef6fc6f36829c/auth/src/desktop/rpcs/auth_request.cc#L87-L91). If `USE_AUTH_EMULATOR` is not set, the SDK logs that message to inform you that it is connecting to the live Firebase Auth service.

If `USE_AUTH_EMULATOR` is set with any other value, the SDK will connect to the Firebase Auth Emulator instead, based on the relevant configuration from the `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable, falling back to `localhost:9099` if that is also not present.